# How do I filter php json for matching keys

Tags: php, html, json, ajax

I intend the php function to return me the list  of all the keys if the value equal or are less than the variable

```
 <?php 
 $t = 35;
 $jsonobj = '{"ABC":35,"DEF":36,"GEH":34}';
 $obj = json_decode($jsonobj);
 foreach($obj as $key => $value){
 if ($t <= $value) {

      {echo $key . " => " . $value . "<br>";}}

 else{
        echo "No result match";
          }
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: What is the desired output ?

Comment: Does it answer your question ? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4944796a06611e18d1a75a49f3a58f084f65dae6

Comment: You are looping over the individual items there, so it makes of course no sense to put `echo "No result match";` _inside_ the loop - you _can not_ determine inside the loop, whether no items matched at all. Stuff like this needs to be done using a boolean flag that you toggle inside the loop, when you find a matching item, and that you then check _after_ the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Decode your JSON as array an use [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to filter out elements:

```
$jsonobj = '{"ABC":35,"DEF":36,"GEH":34}';
$array = json_decode($jsonobj, true);

print_r(array_filter($array, "lessthan"));

function lessthan($var) {
    return $var <= 35;
}
```

Will output

```
Array
(
    [ABC] => 35
    [GEH] => 34
)
```

Edit: if you want to use/keep your `$t` you can do like so:

```
<?php

$t = 35;
$jsonobj = '{"ABC":35,"DEF":36,"GEH":34}';
$array = json_decode($jsonobj, true);

print_r(array_filter($array, function ($var) use ($t) {
    return $var <= $t;
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain your style of coding then I recommend looping the array and adding to a new array if true.

```
$t = 35;
$jsonobj = '{"ABC":35,"DEF":36,"GEH":34}';
$obj = json_decode($jsonobj);
$match =[];
foreach($obj as $key => $value){
    if ($t <= $value) {
        $match[] = $key . " => " . $value;
    }
}

if(count($match) > 0){
    echo implode("<br>\n", $match);
}else{
    echo "no matches";
}
```

See it running here:
https://3v4l.org/NDuD7